# Modal box isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I am writing a small webapp and I decided I will not use any framework. I will write only vanilla javascript.

The problem I have is that I want to be able to open three different types of modal windows with different keyboard keys. For example, <kbd>g</kbd> will open one type, <kbd>d</kbd> will open another, and <kbd>m</kbd> yet another.

I tried to implement the <kbd>g</kbd> one, which will contain a title and an input form, and the <kbd>d</kbd> one, with a title and two buttons. Here is my code so far:

```
var width = 720;
var height = 350;
var modal = document.createElement('div');
modal.className  = "modal";
modal.style.width = width;
modal.style.height = height;
modal.style.position = 'absolute';
modal.style.top = (window.innerHeight - parseInt(modal.style.height)) / 2 +'px';
modal.style.left = (window.innerWidth - parseInt(modal.style.width)) / 2 +'px';

var ngroup = modal;
var title = document.createElement('span');
title.innerHTML = "TYPE GROUP NAME"
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = "text";
ngroup.appendChild(title);
ngroup.appendChild(input);

var del = modal;
var dtitle = document.createElement('span');
dtitle.innerHTML = "DO YO WANT TO DELETE SELECTED COLOR(S)"
var dinput = document.createElement('input');
dinput.type = "button";
dinput.value = "yes";
var dinput1 = document.createElement('input');
dinput1.type = "button";
dinput1.value = "no";
del.appendChild(dtitle);
del.appendChild(dinput);
del.appendChild(dinput1);   
function openModal(type) {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.appendChild(type);
}
function closeModal() {
  document.body.removeChild(modal);
}
```

and this is *modal.js*, which is included in the main page and called by this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 71) {
        openModal(del);
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 39) {
        closeModal();
    }
});
```

When I hit <kbd>g</kbd>, it opens a modal with every element: two titles, one text field and two buttons. Why? What is the problem with my Javascript? I know it’s still not organized, but I’d like to make things work before getting into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you aren't using a library, I would recommend using the same tactic as jQuery. Specifically, I would specify all three dialogs in the static HTML in a hidden `div`. For example, the following would be the 'd' dialog:

```
<div id="d_dialog" style="display:none" class="dialog">
    <span>DO YO WANT TO DELETE SELECTED COLOR(S)</span>
    <input type="button" value="yes"/>
    <input type="button" value="no"/>
</div>
```

Then, from JavaScript when you want to open the dialog, just show the hidden `div`.

```
document.getElementById('d_dialog').style.display = '';
```

This will make your work much more maintainable than creating all the HTML elements from JavaScript. You can specify the style of the dialog by adding a class called `dialog` to your CSS.

**The specific problem with your code**

The specific problem with your code is you are reassigning the same variable `modal` to multiple other variables.

```
var del = modal;
```

This doesn't make a copy of the modal element. It just makes the new variable del reference the same object as the modal variable. Therefore when you call:

```
del.appendChild(dtitle);
```

It behaves the same as if you had called

```
modal.appendChild(dtitle);
```

So all the controls are added to the `modal` element. And when you show the dialog with

```
opendDialog(del);
```

It behaves as if you had called

```
openDialog(modal);
```

And shows the element with all the controls on it. To make your code work, you should create a function `createModal` that just does the following:

```
function createModal()
{
    var width = 720;
    var height = 350;
    var modal = document.createElement('div');
    modal.className  = "modal";
    modal.style.width = width;
    modal.style.height = height;
    modal.style.position = 'absolute';
    modal.style.top = (window.innerHeight - parseInt(modal.style.height)) / 2 +'px';
    modal.style.left = (window.innerWidth - parseInt(modal.style.width)) / 2 +'px';
    return modal;
}
```

Then, for each of the dialogs, instead of

```
var del = modal;
```

Do

```
var del = createModal();
```

This will create a new element instead of creating a new variable that refers to the same element.

Comment: Thank you, and could you explain me why is this method better? im noob and i want to learn!

Comment: You are right, and i could still specify the position with my Javascript, in order to center it vertically. Nice answer, but i'm still curious about what was the problem with my script! :)

Comment: It will help you maintain your code. When you create HTML from JavaScript it will take more effort to change in the future. Plus the HTML is parsed instead of being interpreted. Plus the HTML is more condensed and will take less bandwidth, and it won't have to be interpreted by the client. Finally, you won't have to worry about the timing of the events, you can show the dialog at any time and you're sure that it will work.

Comment: Se my edit. I point out the exact problem with your code. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you very very much, now it's THE answrt ;)